# Why are bitwise operators slower than multiplication/division/modulo?

Tags: python, optimization, bitwise-operators, micro-optimization

It's a well known fact that multiplication, integer division, and modulo by powers of two can be rewritten more efficiently as bitwise operations:

```
>>> x = randint(50000, 100000)
>>> x << 2 == x * 4
True
>>> x >> 2 == x // 4
True
>>> x & 3 == x % 4
True
```

In compiled languages such as C/C++ and Java, tests have shown that bitwise operations are generally faster than arithmetic operations. (See [here](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1946) and [here](http://mziccard.me/2015/05/08/modulo-and-division-vs-bitwise-operations/)). However, when I test these in Python, I am getting contrary results:

```
In [1]: from random import randint
   ...: nums = [randint(0, 1000000) for _ in range(100000)]

In [2]: %timeit [i * 8 for i in nums]
7.73 ms ± 397 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit [i << 3 for i in nums]
8.22 ms ± 368 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit [i // 8 for i in nums]
7.05 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit [i >> 3 for i in nums]
7.55 ms ± 367 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit [i % 8 for i in nums]
5.96 ms ± 503 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit [i & 7 for i in nums]
8.29 ms ± 816 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see, bitwise operations are slower than their arithmetic counterparts, especially for modulo. I repeated this test for another set of numbers, and got the same result. Is there a reason for this? These tests were in CPython 3.6.7, if that matters.

Comment: Well, for starters, Python `int` objects are nothing like a C `int`, they are *objects*. The underlying representation isn't even a C `int`, it is an array of digits, if you understand C, take a look for yourself: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longintrepr.h This is because Python `int` objects are *arbitrarily sized*, not fixed size.

Comment: divide and modulo by a power of 2 isn't a great test; any decent C compiler would compile that to a shift.  (Or for signed `i`, shifts + stuff to get the rounding semantics right for possibly-negative `i`).  I don't expect that CPython will, but if you want to compare it to C, use a runtime-variable divisor.  (Otherwise `i / 12345` can still compile to a fast multiply / shift.  [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935).  Modern x86 CPUs have very high performance multiply that's about as fast as 3 shifts.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am aware compilers make such optimizations, so I used the `dis` module to check that `i % <power of 2>` is not doing a bit shift, and I far as I could tell, it wasn't. However, maybe the optimization was further down so the `dis` module could not reveal it... I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know much about Python internals, but such an optimization is only likely / really good at a point where the optimization can be done once for a constant, not every time through the loop.  Checking `x & (x-1) == 0` to check for a power of 2, then using a bit-scan like POSIX `ffs()` or x86 `bsf` / `tzcnt` to get a shift count is probably not worth it unless the implementation expects powers of 2 to be very common.  (And then only for divide if at all, not multiply, unless the input has multiple limbs).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`*`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.7/Objects/longobject.c#L3578), [`%`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.7/Objects/longobject.c#L4015), and [`/`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.7/Objects/longobject.c#L3736) all have fast paths for single-"limb" integers. [`<<`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.7/Objects/longobject.c#L4349), [`>>`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.7/Objects/longobject.c#L4293), and [`&`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.7/Objects/longobject.c#L4546) don't. They're going through the general-purpose arbitrary-precision code path.

Comment: So this "fast path" you speak of is occurring in the interpretation of the code, correct?

Comment: It's in the operator implementations.

Comment: Thanks, the source code to the implementations was helpful. One more thing, could you elaborate on what "single-limb" integers are?

Comment: Limbs are digits, but bigger. It doesn't look like the CPython source uses the term; I got the term from reading about GMP. The CPython source just uses "digit".

Comment: So, to clarify, for extremely large numbers, will the bitwise operators be faster?

Comment: @Tomothy32: a "limb" is a base-2^30 "digit", stored as a binary integer in a `uint32_t` or equivalent.  CPython stores big integers in chunks of that size.  Just like how you can add decimal numbers on paper one digit at a time, using base-2^30 digits allows CPython to get lots of work done with each primitive add operation the CPU does.  (Using base 2^32 chunks would allow using add / add-with-carry in asm to take advantage of hardware support for big-integers on most architectures, but that's not what CPython does.  2^30 has some advantages, though, esp. for pure C without asm.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the explanation, I couldn't find anything well-documented about limbs online!

Comment: Update: [BigInt class in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237764) includes some more details and a link to code for CPython's bigint stuff. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db842f730432/Include/longintrepr.h#l10 / https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/

Answer (score 1):

I test large numbers, and the bitwise operators is faster.

```
python -m timeit '[i for i in range(10**64, 10**64+1000) if i & 0b10==0]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 238 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[i for i in range(10**64, 10**64+1000) if i % 2==0]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 303 usec per loop
```

Comment: Those aren't equivalent: the first should be `i & 1`.